# Could not select database

Tags: php, html, mysql, connection

Hi guys I'm trying to write some code for a login, I've got it all but whenever I try login it says **Could not select database**. I can't figure it out, I've got hosting with One.com and when I go into the PHP & MySQL settings it says the database name is "c343_co_uk", which is what I've used in the code below:

UPDATE: It's detecting the database but whenever I try and log in with the exact same username and password that's on MySQL it says invalid login

Here is my **Connection.php**

```
<?php
$username = "c343_co_uk";
$password = "abc";
$hostname = "c343.co.uk.mysql"; 

//connection to the database
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");


$selected = mysql_select_db("c343_co_uk",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select Database");

?>
```

**Loginform.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<a href="index.html" title="back to home">Home</a>
</font>
    <head>

        <style>
            body {
                font-size: 14px;
            }

        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css" />
    </head>
    <body> 


    <div id="loginform" style="font-family: 'ClearSans-Thin'; color: Black">


        Please enter your login details<br /><br />
        Username:<br />
        <form method="post" action="loginsubmit.php">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <br />
            Password:<br />
            <input type="password" name="password" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Loginsubmit.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php

include 'connection.php';
include 'loginform.php';
?>
<center>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
    $user = $_POST['username'];

    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    //Counts up how many matches there are in the database
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM users WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $queryadmin = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM admin WHERE Username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user) . "' && Password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pass). "'";
    $resultadmin = mysqli_query($connection, $queryadmin);
    $rowadmin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadmin);
    //If count is more than 0, log user in.
    if ($row["cnt"] > 0) 
    {
        $_SESSION["userlogged"] =  $user;
        echo "Logged in - Press the home button to return to the homepage";
    } 
    //count for user table is 0, if there are more than 0 matches in the admin database, start admin session
    else if ($rowadmin["cnt"] > 0 )
        {
            $_SESSION["adminlogged"] = $user;
            echo "Logged in - Press the home button to return to the homepage";
        }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Not a valid login';
    }
}
?>
</center>
```

Comment: Where do you define `$dbhandle`?

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error()` to see what the actual error message is.

Comment: I swapped dbhandle with connection, now it's connecting, my bad! However it doesn't recognise the credentials from the table, so says invalid login,.

Answer (score 1):

try these:

```
 $dbname = "c343_co_uk"
 $username = "c343_co_uk";
 $password = "abc";
 $hostname = "c343.co.uk.mysql";
```

and replace

```
    $selected = mysql_select_db("c343_co_uk",$connection) 
  or die("Could not select Database");
```

to this:

```
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect) 
  or die("Could not select Database");
```

i hope that work! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
$selected = mysql_select_db("c343_co_uk",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select Database");
```

with

```
$selected = mysql_select_db("c343_co_uk",$connection) 
  or die("Could not select Database");
```

Comment: Actually it's now a new error saying it's not a valid login, I will copy & paste the loginsubmit php code and login form, one sec :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for connection :-

```
$username = "c343_co_uk";

$password = "abc";

$hostname = "c343.co.uk.mysql";

$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

@mysql_select_db("c343_co_uk",$connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try by this way

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "c343.co.uk.mysql");
define("DB_USER", "c343_co_uk");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "abc");
define("DB_DATABASE", "c343_co_uk");
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE );

?>
```

Comment: Why?  What problem is this going to resolve..?  Plesae explain.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't do the host with mysql, just do c343.co.uk:

```
 <?php
 $username = "c343_co_uk";
 $password = "abc";
 $hostname = "c343.co.uk"; 

 //connection to the database
 $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
   or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");


 $selected = mysql_select_db("c343_co_uk",$dbhandle) 
   or die("Could not select Database");

 ?>
```

I hope this work! other i'll take a look again